# Alert with jqGrid error messages

Tags: jqgrid, alert, jsonreader

I would like to get an alert when errors occur when loading my jqGrid table. For instance, when the jsonReader is not well configured, like when repeatitems is true instead of false, U can see in Firebug the error:

```
ccur is undefined
[Break On This Error] idr = ccur[idn] || idr;
```

How can I place such an error in an alert? I have already tried using `loadError`, but it doesn't work, because it is not even triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems for me that you should just use `try - catch` block over jqGrid code:

```
try {
    // create the grid
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        // all jqGrid options
    });
} catch (err) {
    // display the error message which you want
    alert(err);
}
```

**UPDATED**: You are right, the `try {...} catch (err) {...}` which I described before work in IE only with reading local data. In case of getting data from the server the exception take place inside of `success` callback of `$.ajax`. To be exactly it take place inside of `addJSONData` or `addXmlData` depend of the type of data which you use. To catch the exception you should modify code of jqGrid in [the place](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.base.js#L1717). The modified code can be about the following

```
success:function(data,st, xhr) {
    if ($.isFunction(ts.p.beforeProcessing)) {
            ts.p.beforeProcessing.call(ts, data, st, xhr);
    }
    try {
        if(dt === "xml") { addXmlData(data,ts.grid.bDiv,rcnt,npage>1,adjust); }
        else { addJSONData(data,ts.grid.bDiv,rcnt,npage>1,adjust); }
        if(lc) { lc.call(ts,data); }
        if (pvis) { ts.grid.populateVisible(); }
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
    if( ts.p.loadonce || ts.p.treeGrid) {ts.p.datatype = "local";}
    data=null;
    if (npage === 1) { endReq(); }
}
```

I tested in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11__.htm) the corresponding modified version of jquery.jqGrid.src.js which display error message. I don't reproduced exactly the error which you described so the error message is a little other as in your case.

If you need minimized version of the modified jquery.jqGrid.src.js file you can produce it yourself with any JavaScript minimizer. For example [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) can be free downloaded and installed. The usage as

```
ajaxmin.exe jquery.jqGrid.src.js -out jquery.jqGrid.min.js
```

will produce the new minimized version of jquery.jqGrid.src.js which will be even a little smaller as the original jquery.jqGrid.min.js.

Another good minimizer is available online [here](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home). You should use "Simple" Optimization only.

Comment: I have already tried that and it didn't work.  Someone told me that it's because jqgrid code is already with a big try catch, so I don't have a chance to do what I want. I am not sure of that though, which is why I posted the question.